# Why the script is not working now as before?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the top of the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

public class DetectPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject target;
    int counter = 0;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform")
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Platform");
        }        
    }
```

I'm using a debugger and a break point and it does getting to the line

```
if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform")
```

And on the property name of the gameObject i see: "ThirdPersonController" but it's never get in to the Debug.Log

The script is attached to the Platform like it show in the screenshot. I'm running the game move the player to the Platform when it touch it it stop on the break point but never enter to the Debug.Log

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collision.gameObject.name` will be called on the **gameobject** which your collider is attached to so if your **collider** is not attached to the game object which is named **platform** , then it wouldn`t be called.

Answer (score 1):

I think @MiladQasemi is right, but I'll try explaining it another way.

The problem as I see it, is your **script** is attached to your **Platform** object, and therefore the code `if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform")` will never be true. **Because the script and the platform are one**, an object cannot collide with itself.

Change the code to be:

```
if (collision.gameObject.name == "ThirdPersonController")
```